# sparql query insert data was not save in owl

Tags: sparql, owl

I try to add a new user to owl with sparql insert data from a user register. When I check individual instances has showing in browser but when I check in protege, the data was not added or when I restart the program, the data was lossed.

```
graph2 = graph.get_context(onto)
graph2.update("""
    PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
    PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    PREFIX gr: <http://www.semanticweb.org/bentofuascarvalho/ontologies/OntoBase#>

   INSERT {
         gr:""" + username + """ rdf:type gr:Person.
     } WHERE {}""")
```

How to save a new data to synchronize with in Protege and in python?

Thanks...!

Comment: well, you have to save the graph to disk back and then force a reload in Protege - all your changes are just done in-memory as the whole ontology is loaded into memory.

Comment: Sorry, I'm newbie...Are these have any function to handle it?

Comment: not sure what you mean. You're using some Python API for parsing RDF data, this clearly also has the option to write RDF data to disk. Did you check the documentation?